# Iterating and ploting five columns per iteration pandas

Tags: pandas, for-loop, seaborn

I am trying to plot five columns per iteration, but current code is ploting everithing five times. How to explain to it to plot five columns per iteration without repeting them?

```
n=4
for tag_1,tag_2,tag_3,tag_4,tag_5 in zip(df.columns[n:], df.columns[n+1:], df.columns[n+2:], df.columns[n+3:], df.columns[n+4:]):
    fig,ax=plt.subplots(ncols=5, tight_layout=True, sharey=True, figsize=(20,3))
    sns.scatterplot(df, x=tag_1, y='variable', ax=ax[0])
    sns.scatterplot(df, x=tag_2, y='variable', ax=ax[1])
    sns.scatterplot(df, x=tag_3, y='variable', ax=ax[2])
    sns.scatterplot(df, x=tag_4, y='variable', ax=ax[3])
    sns.scatterplot(df, x=tag_5, y='variable', ax=ax[4])
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using list slicing in the wrong way. When you use `df.columns[n:]`, you are getting all the column names from the one with index `n` to the last one. The same is valid for `n+1`, `n+2`, `n+3` and `n+4`. This causes the repetition that you are referring to. In addition to that, the fact that the plot is shown five times is due to the behavior of the [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function: when used on iterables with different sizes, the iterable returned by `zip` has the size of the smaller one (in this case `df.columns[n+4:]`).

You can achieve what you want by adapting your code as follows:

```
# Imports to create sample data
import string
import random

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

# Create some sample data and a sample dataframe
data = { string.ascii_lowercase[i]: [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(100)] for i in range(15) }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Iterate in groups of five indexes
for start in range(0, len(df.columns), 5):

    # Get the next five columns. Pay attention to the case in which the number of columns is not a multiple of 5
    cols = [df.columns[idx] for idx in range(start, min(start+5, len(df.columns)))]

    # Adapt your plot and take into account that the last group can be smaller than 5
    fig,ax=plt.subplots(ncols=len(cols), tight_layout=True, sharey=True, figsize=(20,3))
    for idx in range(len(cols)):
        #sns.scatterplot(df, x=cols[idx], y='variable', ax=ax[idx]) 
        sns.scatterplot(df, x=cols[idx], y=df[cols[idx]], ax=ax[idx]) # In the example the values of the column are plotted
    plt.show()
```

In this case, the code performs the following steps:

1. Iterate over groups of at most five indexes ([0->4], [5->10]...)
2. Recover the columns that are positioned in the previously recovered indexes. The last group of columns may be smaller than 5 (e.g., 18 columns, the last is composed of the ones with the following indexes: 15, 16, 17
3. Create the plot taking into account the previous corner case of less than 5 columns

Answer (score 0):

With [Seaborn's object interface](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/objects_interface.html#faceting-and-pairing-subplots), available from v0.12, we might do like this:

```py
from numpy import random

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import seaborn.objects as so

sns.set_theme()
```

First, let's create a sample dataset, just like [trolloldem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75246811/iterating-and-ploting-five-columns-per-iteration-pandas#75248245).

```py
random.seed(0)   # To produce the same random values across multiple runs
columns = list("abcdefghij")
sample_size = 20

df_orig = pd.DataFrame(
    {c: random.randint(100, size=sample_size) for c in columns},
    index=pd.Series(range(sample_size), name="variable")
)
```

Then transform the data frame into a [long-form](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data) for easier processing.

```py
df = (df_orig
    .melt(value_vars=columns, var_name="tag", ignore_index=False)
    .reset_index()
)
```

Then finally render the figures, 5 figures per row.

```py
(
    so.Plot(df, x="value", y="variable") # Or you might do x="variable", y="value" instead
    .facet(col="tag", wrap=5)
    .add(so.Dot())
)
```

[image: the result scatter plots]